# RedBlack Trees: I am trying to understand deletion of nodes in redblack trees?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, red-black-tree

I am following the reference at [Algorithms princetion robert et al, ebook](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/33balanced/) to learn algorithms. I am not able to figure out deletions in red-black trees any help would be great. 
The book talks about coding the deletion in correspondence with as it would have been done in 2-3 trees. I can't make the correlation.thanks

Answer (score 1):

Refer wikipedia, a detailed explanation was given here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Removal

Comment: that's fine but I am specifically trying to understand the **left-leaning-red** black bst as described in the link above

Answer (score 0):

Sedgewick's paper says it beautifully, in my opinion: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/LLRB/LLRB.pdf

The intuition behind delete is this: a red-black tree is simply an encoding of a 2-3-4 tree or a 2-3 tree, depending on how you implement it (the red links are used to construct 3- and 4-nodes using ordinary 2-nodes).  When deleting, we perform rotations on the way down to guarantee that we ultimately end up deleting the target from a leaf 3-node or 4-node (which can be done by simply removing the target element).  Then there may be some fix-up rotations on the way back up the tree to restore the tree invariants.

Cheers!